# How much time do I have after applicationWillTerminate invoked?

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

I would like to save an image objects before the app terminate. How much time approximatively do I have ?

Comment: You should save data and state each time your app enters the background. Don't wait until it is about to be terminated.

Comment: Not only that, you should have a really good reason for disabling background mode.  Most apps behave really poorly if they have to start fresh on every "launch".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol documentation of `applicationWillTerminate` method:

> ... Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before
>   time expires, the system may kill the process altogether. ...

Comment: Note that this is actually not always true. For example, if your app is set to not support background execution, it will get terminated IMMEDIATELY after this method is called. There is no time for saving data.